# Плагин ХРОМ Поиск текста по страниц

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, веб-программирование, chrome-extension

Добрый день. Пишу плагин для поиска текста по странице.

**POPUP.HTML**

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="text-to-find"> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: searchTextOnPage('text-to-find'); return false;"/>
</body>
```

**Обработчик:**

```
var lastResFind=""; // последний удачный результат
var copy_page=""; // копия страницы в ихсодном виде
function TrimStr(s) {
     s = s.replace( /^\s+/g, '');
  return s.replace( /\s+$/g, '');
}
function FindOnPage(inputId) {//ищет текст на странице, в параметр передается ID поля для ввода
  var obj = window.document.getElementById(inputId);
  var textToFind;

  if (obj) {
    textToFind = TrimStr(obj.value);//обрезаем пробелы
  } else {
    alert("Введенная фраза не найдена");
    return;
  }
  if (textToFind == "") {
    alert("Вы ничего не ввели");
    return;
  }

  if(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(textToFind)=="-1")
  alert("Ничего не найдено, проверьте правильность ввода!");

  if(copy_page.length>0)
        document.body.innerHTML=copy_page;
  else copy_page=document.body.innerHTML;


  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/name="+lastResFind+"/gi")," ");//стираем предыдущие якори для скрола
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/"+textToFind+"/gi"),"<a name="+textToFind+" style='background:red'>"+textToFind+"</a>"); //Заменяем найденный текст ссылками с якорем;
  lastResFind=textToFind; // сохраняем фразу для поиска, чтобы в дальнейшем по ней стереть все ссылки
  window.location = '#'+textToFind;//перемещаем скрол к последнему найденному совпадению
 }
```

Но он не работает, как я понял, потому-что инлайн скрипты запрещены, из-за:

```
<input type="text" id="text-to-find"> 
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: searchTextOnPage('text-to-find'); return false;"/>
```

Я не очень хорошо знаю JS, помогите вынести это в обработчик, что-бы при клике искалось, то, что в текстовое поле ввел пользователь, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Вам всего-лишь необходимо разместить обработчик на клик внутри скрипта:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var input = document.querySelector('#text-to-find');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var text = input.value;
    searchTextOnPage(text); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

А где вы вызываете функцию FindOnPage()?

Может так надо:

```
<input type="button" onclick="FindOnPage('text-to-find'); return false;"/>
```

Comment: дело в том, что если запускать не как плагин, то все работает

Comment: в плагинах хрома запрещено использовать инлайн скрипты, мне надо как-то передать то, что пользователь ввел в инпут в лежащий в файле скрипт

Comment: а это да, заметил, поправил
onclick="FindOnPage('text-to-find')

Comment: Инлайновый JS не работает в раширениях для Google Chrome